# How to parse XML that an element not always has the same structure

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have an application in C# where I'm inspecting SOAP messages between client and server.

The request and response are always XML serialization. Part of the message has the action method and I need to get just the method but I have seen that the element that I need in the XML not always has the same name:

Here is an example:

This is the element that I need to parse:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IMember/GetAuthorizations</a:Action>
```

It can also appears sometimes like this:

```
<Action d1p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://tempuri.org/IMember/GetAuthorizations</Action>
```

What I need to get is the **Method** of the URL, in this case I need to parse this element so I can get **GetAuthorizations**

> Any clue on how can I parse both? I don't know when it comes in the first way or in the second.

Comment: It seems they are both the same XML but with namespaces applied differently. How are you parsing the XML? A proper XML parser should take those namespaces into account.

Comment: Can you treat it like a string? If all else fails, you could probably make the distinction very easily that way, and then shuffle it off to the correct parser... if indeed that's your intent.

Comment: Yes actually is a string

Comment: Your first XML fragment is invalid: it's missing a definition of the `a` namespace.  (Try uploading it [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/).)  Your second fragment is, on the other hand, valid.  This leads me to believe you may have omitted the XML root node from your question.  Can you edit your question to include the XML root node and any intermediate nodes down to the `Action` node, for both cases?

Comment: @VAAA I assume this is only portion of the entire XML. If that's correct, you need to show declaration of `a` and `s` prefixes too. That's significant to tell if both XML will be considered the same by parser

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string input = "<a:Action xmlns:a=\"http://tempuri.org\" xmlns:s=\"http://tempuri.org\" s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">\"http://tempuri.org/IMember/GetAuthorizations\"</a:Action>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            string mustUnderstand = doc.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Action").Attributes().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "mustUnderstand").FirstOrDefault().Value;​
```